# 'using' keyword with multiple overloads

Tags: c++

I have been reading how to use [using-declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) and was wondering what happened when I have multiple overloads. In the examples given, it looks as if this is all or nothing or is it possible to pull only a certain signature in scope?

Suppose I have the following classes:

```
class A
{
public:
   void function(int value);
   void function(double value);
   void function(const char *value);
};


class B : public A
{
public:
    using A::function;
    void function(uint64_t value);
};
```

Now in `class B` with the `using` keyword, I introduce the base class members into my class namespace. But this means that all of them are now available, right? Or can I also specify the signature, because I only want to introduce one of them, but not all. From the examples given, I would expect no. So in this case, I would have to move the declaration of such a function to `protected` or `private` to disable access to it, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's all or nothing, you can't pick only specific overloads.

> I would have to move the declaration of such a function to protected or private to disable access to it, right?

It wouldn't work. If you move even some of them to `private`, then `using A::function;` will apparently cause an error.

And if you make them `protected`, it wouldn't do anything, because `using ...` changes the access level on names you give it (i.e. if the `using` is `public`, the inherited functions become `public` too).

Comment: Ah, thanks for that clarification! I was not aware of that. So in this case I would have to write stubs with the appropriate visibillity, instead of `using`.

Comment: @Devolus: It's also confusing because you're using public inheritance. So to an outsider all the functions are visible and public. If you want to hide some of them, consider composition.

Comment: @MooingDuck, yeah, this was just a made up example to illustrate the point, because I was curious about it. I was looking up the `using` keyword in some other context and it got me thinking about this szenario.

Comment: @Devolus If you still want some of them `public` and others `private`, but without writing a lot of proxy overloads in `B`, you could make a template in `B` instead of `using`, like `template<class T> void function(T value) { A::function(value); }`

Comment: @Devolus Stubs **plus** `using` would just give you ambiguous overloads errors. You need to wrap them in new functions, like `void function(int value) {A::function(value);}`.